A trigonometric equation: how hard could it be?
The following problem started out with a formulation in terms of complex numbers: let $\epsilon=e^{\frac{\pi i}3}$ and $z=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3(2n-1)}}$. It's rather amusing that the following appears to be true, numerically.

QUESTION. Is this true?
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{z^k(1+\epsilon z^{3k})}{1-z^{6k}} = 
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \epsilon z^k \cdot\frac{z^k(1+\epsilon z^{3k})}{1-z^{6k}}.$$

but I thought one could have a different or feasible approach via trigonometric functions. So, here it is.
QUESTION. If $n$ is a positive integer and $x=\frac{\pi}{3(2n-1)}$ then is this true?
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\tan(kx) - \tan\left(kx+\frac{\pi}3\right)
+3\tan\left(kx+\frac{\pi}6\right) - 3\tan\left(3kx +\frac{\pi}2 \right) \right)=0.$$

Is this a re-phrasing of your now-deleted question The equality of two sums involving roots of unity?

It is, yes. Maybe it is possible to solve this way.

@T.Amdeberhan it probably would've been better not to delete that question and instead just edit it to note the possible re-phrasing.

A surprisingly tricky question.  The identity $\frac{1}{1-z^{6k}} = -\frac{1}{2n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{2n-2} (j+1) z^{6jk}$ can be used to convert it to a polynomial identity in $z$, but I'm not finding the algebraic miracle to simplify the resulting expression.  For some strange reason I'm getting hints that character sum identities and possibly quadratic reciprocity are relevant, though.

@T.Amdeberhan Are the two formulations given equivalent?

What inspired this conjecture? How does one accidentally numerically come across it?

The trigonometric form of the conjecture can be simplified. Starting from the last display in the OP's response below (which is a result of the residue theorem), we obtain the equivalent conjecture $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\bigl(\csc(2kx)+\tan(\pi/6+kx)-\tan(\pi/6+2kx)\bigr)=0.$$ This can be further simplified via $\pi/6=\pi/2-(2n-1)x$ and $\tan(\pi/2-t)=\cot(t)$.

@GHfromMO Note the equivalence does not need the residue theorem, and it can be arrived at from the identity $3\tan3x=\tan x+\tan(x+\pi/3)+\tan(x-\pi/3)$ followed by several more elementary identities. I derived it this way but I couldn't make any realistic progress after that.

@TheSimpliFire My point was that the OP derived the trigonometric form of the conjecture from the residue theorem (more precisely he derived the equivalence of the two conjectures by applying the residue theorem), and in fact this process yields directly the simpler trigonometric form above.

@TheSimpliFire In fact the equivalence of the two conjectures follows in an elementary fashion (without the residue theorem). See my second comment below the OP's response.

In the comments, GH from MO shows that it suffices to prove that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (\csc(2kx)+\tan(\pi/6+kx)-\tan(\pi/6+2kx))=0,\tag{$\ast$}
$$
and suggests replacing $\tan$ with $\cot$ using $\pi/6=\pi/2-(2n-1)x$ and $\tan(\pi/2-t)=\cot(t)$; here $x=\pi/(6n-3)$ as in the original post. Following this suggestion, the statement becomes
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (\csc(2kx)+\cot((2n-1-k)x)-\cot((2n-1-2k)x))=0.
$$
Using the identity $\csc(2t)=\cot(t)-\cot(2t)$, and then rearranging the terms, we get the equivalent form
$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \cot(kx)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \cot((2n-1-k)x)\right)-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \cot(2kx) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \cot((2n-1-2k)x)\right)=0.
$$
If we adjust the indices, we are left with proving
$$
\left(\sum_{m=1}^{2n-2} \cot(mx)\right)-\left(\sum_{m=1}^{2n-2} \cot(mx)\right)=0.
$$
However, this is obvious, and the proof is complete.
Added by GH from MO. To make this post self-contained, we explain why $(\ast)$ is equivalent to
the originally conjectured identity. Using the OP's notation $\epsilon=e^{\frac{\pi i}3}$ and $z=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3(2n-1)}}$,
we can rewrite the identity in question as
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{z^k(1+\epsilon z^{3k})(1-\epsilon z^k)}{1-z^{6k}} = 0.$$
Here
$$\frac{z^k(1+\epsilon z^{3k})(1-\epsilon z^k)}{1-z^{6k}} = \frac{1-\epsilon^2}{3}\left(\frac{z^k}{1-z^{2k}}-\frac1{1+\epsilon z^k}+\frac1{1+\epsilon z^{2k}} \right),$$
whence the identity in question is equivalent to
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{z^k}{1-z^{2k}}-\frac1{1+\epsilon z^k}+\frac1{1+\epsilon z^{2k}} \right)=0.$$
We can turn this into $(\ast)$ by applying
$$\frac{e^{i\theta}}{1-e^{2i\theta}}=\frac{i\csc\theta}{2},\qquad\frac1{1+e^{2i\theta}}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i\tan\theta}{2}.$$
As Terry Tao remarked in a comment below this post, the story can be told directly without recourse to trigonometric functions.

To combine all the arguments: for any complex number $w$, one has the partial fraction expansion $\frac{w(1+\epsilon w^3)(1-\epsilon w)}{1-w^6} = \frac{1-\epsilon^2}{3} (\frac{1}{1-w^{-2}} + \frac{1}{1+\epsilon w^2} - \frac{1}{1-w^{-1}} - \frac{1}{1+\epsilon w})$.  Substituting $w=z^k$ and using $\epsilon = - z^{-(2n-1)}$ we conclude $\frac{z^k(1+\epsilon z^{3k})(1-\epsilon z^k)}{1-z^{6k}} = \frac{1-\epsilon^3}{3} (\frac{1}{1-z^{-2k}} + \frac{1}{1- z^{-(2n-1-2k)}} - \frac{1}{1-z^{-k}} - \frac{1}{1-z^{-(2n-1-k)}})$.  Summing over $k=1,\dots,n-1$, the terms all cancel.

In particular, this gives a very circuitious proof of my character sum identity.  I wonder if there is a more direct proof of that identity.

@TerryTao: three things: (1) thanks to you, the question drew more attention; (2) we got to see a more sophisticated character sum of definite interest; (3) you now sparked a new problem of proving the character sum identity by a direct attack. In the end, I like to say that innocent-looking problems could be catalysts for rich mathematics. A lesson for some "naysayers".

I'll pose the problem of finding a direct proof of this identity as a separate question.

Now posted at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/472894/direct-proof-of-a-character-sum-identity

I can't prove the identity, but I found that it implies a rather strange Dirichlet character sum identity, so I am recording the implication here in case anyone recognizes the latter.
I will specialize to the case where $2n-1$ is coprime to $3$.
I prefer to write $\epsilon = -\omega^2$, where $\omega := e^{2\pi i/3} = z^{2n-1}$ is a cube root of unity.  Collect all the terms to one side:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{z^k + \omega^2 z^{2k} - \omega^2 z^{4k} - \omega z^{5k}}{1-z^{6k}} = 0.$$
From the easily verified "discrete sawtooth Fourier series" identity
$$ \frac{1}{1-z^{6k}} = -\frac{1}{2n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{2n-2} j z^{6jk}$$
for any $k$ not divisible by $2n-1$ (proven by multiplying out the denominator, cancelling terms, and applying the geometric series formula), we write the preceding identity to prove as
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{2n-2} j \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (z^{(6j+1)k} + \omega^2 z^{(6j+2)k} - \omega^2 z^{(6j+4)k} - \omega z^{(6j+5)k}) = 0.$$
[Remark: at this point one could use the geometric series formula to sum in $k$, but this returns us to an identity of similar complexity to the one we are originally trying to prove, and I wasn't able to get much further pursuing that route.]
Assuming $2n-1$ is coprime to $3$, we can write $z = \omega^{2n-1} \zeta$ for some primitive $(2n-1)^{\mathrm{th}}$ root $\zeta$ of unity.  We then reduce to
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{2n-2} j\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (\omega^{(2n-1)k} \zeta^{(6j+1)k} + \omega^{2(2n-1)k+2} \zeta^{(6j+2)k} - \omega^{(2n-1)k+2} \zeta^{(6j+4)k} - \omega^{2(2n-1)k+1} \zeta^{(6j+5)k}) = 0.$$
From Galois theory we see that the net coefficient of $\zeta^a$ would have to be independent of $a$ for each primitive residue class $a$ mod $2n-1$.  In particular, if $\chi : {\bf Z}/(2n-1){\bf Z} \to S^1$ is a non-principal Dirichlet character of period $2n-1$, then a necessary identity to establish is
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{2n-2} j \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (\omega^{(2n-1)k} \chi((6j+1)k) + \omega^{2(2n-1)k+2} \chi((6j+2)k) - \omega^{(2n-1)k+2} \chi((6j+4)k) - \omega^{2(2n-1)k+1} \chi((6j+5)k) = 0.$$
The point of doing this is that the left-hand side factorizes as
$$ a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 - a_3 b_3 - a_4 b_4$$
where the $a_i, b_i$ are character sums
$$ a_1 := \sum_{j=0}^{2n-2} j \chi(6j+1)$$
$$ a_2 := \sum_{j=0}^{2n-2} j \chi(6j+2)$$
$$ a_3 := \sum_{j=0}^{2n-2} j \chi(6j+4)$$
$$ a_4 := \sum_{j=0}^{2n-2} j \chi(6j+5)$$
and
$$ b_1 := \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \omega^{(2n-1)k} \chi(k)$$
$$ b_2 := \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \omega^{2(2n-1)k+2} \chi(k)$$
$$ b_3 := \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \omega^{(2n-1)k+2} \chi(k)$$
$$ b_4 := \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \omega^{2(2n-1)k+1} \chi(k)$$
At this point a minor algebraic miracle occurs (which possibly suggests that one is on the right track): by using the substitution $j \mapsto 2n-2-j$ (as well as the mean zero nature of $\chi$) one can check that
$$ a_4 = -\chi(-1) a_1; \quad a_3 = -\chi(-1) a_2$$
and similarly
$$ \chi(-1) b_3 = \sum_{k=1-n}^{-1} \omega^{2(2n-1)k+2} \chi(k)$$
$$ \chi(-1) b_4 = \sum_{k=1-n}^{-1} \omega^{(2n-1)k+1} \chi(k) = \sum_{k=n}^{2n-2} \omega^{(2n-1)k} \chi(k)$$
and so we arrive at the curious character sum identity
$$(\sum_{j=0}^{2n-2} j \chi(6j+1)) (\sum_{k=1}^{2n-2} \omega^{(2n-1)k} \chi(k)) = -(\sum_{j=0}^{2n-2} j \chi(6j+2)) (\sum_{k=1-n}^{n-1} \omega^{2(2n-1)k+2} \chi(k)),$$
which is valid whenever $2n-1$ is coprime to $3$ and $\chi: {\bf Z}/(2n-1){\bf Z} \to S^1$ is a non-principal Dirichlet character.  I can verify this identity numerically, but I do not know why it is true in general; these are not character sums that I recognize any identities for, though it is faintly reminiscent of some character sums that arise in some proofs of quadratic reciprocity.  [Remark: one can try to apply Fourier inversion / Poisson summation to the above character sums (in the spirit of the proof of the Polya-Vinogradov inequality), but then denominators similar to the initial denominators $\frac{1}{1-z^{6k}}$ begin to emerge when doing so, and so one returns to an identity of comparable complexity to the starting identity, though at least without the weird summation range $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}$ that was not so naturally related to the period $3(2n-1)$ of the problem.  This may not necessarily be a bad move - for instance, there could be some miraculous symmetry or cancellation to exploit back in the "denominator" formulation of the problem - but I was not able to get any mileage out of such a transformation.]

Terry Tao: Many thanks for sharing your penetrating insight into bringing even more intriguing properties out of the original question. Since (among many things) you enjoy complex analysis and Fourier series techniques, I would actually like to ask you this: do you see any utility of Residue Theory (choosing a good $f(z)$)? How about applying Poisson's summation to the piece-wise smooth function $f(z)$ to get
$$\sum_{k\in\Bbb{Z}}f(k)=\sum_{\ell\in\Bbb{Z}} \widehat{f}(\ell)$$ to compute our finite sums as integrals over the real line?

Most of my attempts to use these sorts of Fourier or residue identities generated denominators of the form $\frac{1}{1-e^{i\theta}}$ (i.e., cosecant or tangent type terms) for various phases $\theta$, basically because of the discontinuities in the weights (e.g., summing $k$ from $1$ to $n-1$, as opposed to the more natural $1$ to $2n-1$ or $1$ to $3(2n-1)$ coming from periodicity considerations).  The manipulations above are intended to get away from these denominators as much as possible, though they are still implicit in the sawtooth type weights in the final character sum identity.

Perhaps there is some bijective proof of this latter identity though (it vaguely suggests counting the number of ways to factor one primitive residue class as the product of two other residue classes with additional weights and constraints), but I don't see exactly how to proceed here.

Factor $j+1$ can be replaced with simply $j$ since $\sum_{j=0}^{2n-2} z^{6kj} = 0$.

Fair enough; I have globally changed $j+1$ to $j$ in order to clean up the formulae very slightly.

This is not an answer either. Instead I wish to address Nate River's question. In addition, it might help someone take advantage of this approach to solve the problem.
I run into the trigonometric version of the problem when I venture on with an application of Residue Theory. Here is an outline: first, rewrite as Terry Tao did and claim that (I'm still using $\epsilon$ to avoid clash)
if $\epsilon=e^{\frac{\pi i}3}$ and $q=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3(2n-1)}}$ then we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{q^k(1+\epsilon q^{3k})(1-\epsilon q^k)}{1-q^{6k}} = 0.$$
Of course $\epsilon^6=1$, $q^{6n-3}=1$ and $\epsilon^2=q^{2n-1}$. Consider the meromorphic function
$$f(z)=\frac{z(1+\epsilon z^3)(1-\epsilon z)}{1-z^6}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{z-q^k}.$$
Observe that $f(z)$ has singularities (simple poles) at $1, \epsilon, \epsilon^2, \epsilon^3, \epsilon^4, q, q^2, \dots, q^{n-1}$.
Here, we made use of $2n-1$ is odd. Next, we compute the residues at $q, q^2, \dots, q^{n-1}$ and add them together to obtain
$$S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{q^k(1+\epsilon q^{3k})(1-\epsilon q^k)}{1-q^{6k}}.$$
The residue at infinity is calculated to be
$\operatorname{Res}\left(-\frac{f(\frac1z)}{z^2}; 0\right)=0$.
Now, since the sum of the residues of $f(z)$ is zero, we find another way to calculate $S_n$ according to (use also $\epsilon^3=-1$, $\epsilon^4=-\epsilon$,
$\epsilon^5=-\epsilon^2$)
\begin{align*} S_n
&=\frac{1-\epsilon^2}{3}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(\frac{q^k}{1-q^{2k}}-\frac1{1+\epsilon q^k}+\frac1{1+\epsilon q^{2k}} \right).
\end{align*}
That means to prove the original claim amounts to verifying the latter sum being zero. At this point, I used the identity $i\tan\theta=1-\frac2{1+e^{2i\theta}}$ in order to convert the task to a trig identity.
I hope this helps.

I divided the coefficient of the last $k$-sum by $3$ (as was necessary for correctness).

I appreciate that.

In fact the residue theorem is not needed here, since one can obtain directly (using partial fractions) that $$\frac{q^k(1+\epsilon q^{3k})(1-\epsilon q^k)}{1-q^{6k}}=\frac{1-\epsilon^2}{3}\left(\frac{q^k}{1-q^{2k}}-\frac1{1+\epsilon q^k}+\frac1{1+\epsilon q^{2k}} \right).$$
