Direct proof of a character sum identity
Let $n>1$ be a natural number such that $2n-1$ is not divisible by $3$, let $\chi: {\bf Z} \to {\bf C}$ be a non-principal Dirichlet character of period $2n-1$, and let $\omega := e^{2\pi i/3}$.  As a consequence of resolving this recent MathOverflow question, an extremely circuitious proof of the character sum identity
$$\left(\sum_{j=0}^{2n-2} j \chi(6j+1)\right) \left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n-2} \omega^{(2n-1)k} \chi(k)\right) = -\left(\sum_{j=0}^{2n-2} j \chi(6j+2)\right) \left(\sum_{k=1-n}^{n-1} \omega^{2(2n-1)k+2} \chi(k)\right) \tag{1}\label{472894_1}$$
was established.  Is there a direct proof of this identity? Is it a special case (or a consequence) of a more general character sum identity? Could it be related somehow to special values of $L(s,\chi)$, such as $L(1,\chi)$?
Given the existing proof, the obvious set identity
\begin{align*}
&\{k: 1 \leq k \leq n-1\} \uplus \{2n-1-k: 1 \leq k \leq n-1\} \\
={}& \{2k: 1 \leq k \leq n-1\} \uplus \{2n-1-2k: 1 \leq k \leq n-1\}
\end{align*}
may somehow be relevant.
Numerical example: If $n=7$ and $\chi$ is the Dirichlet character
of period $13$ with $\chi(2) = e^{2\pi i/12}$, then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^{2n-2} j \chi(6j+1) &= -3.401 + 8.768i, \qquad
\sum_{j=0}^{2n-2} j \chi(6j+2) = -14.660-10.732i, \\
\sum_{k=1}^{2n-2} \omega^{(2n-1)k} \chi(k) &=  -3.866+3.232i, \qquad
\sum_{k=1-n}^{n-1} \omega^{2(2n-1)k+2} \chi(k)=  -2.134-1.5i
\end{align*}
and both sides of \eqref{472894_1} are equal to $-15.1865-44.892i$.

Geeky TeX note: every other column of an {align}, starting with the second, starts with an invisible atom. So a & = b is (for these purposes) the same as {a}{{}= b}, and spaces as you'd like: ${a}{{}= b}$. But a = & b is the same as {a =}{b}, and doesn't (because the = doesn't know there is something on its right-hand side): ${a =}{b}$. To fix this, one needs the awful construct a ={} & b ${a ={}}{b}$. I edited accordingly. \ I didn't edit in a link to your referenced answer in case you didn't want it in the post, but here it is in a comment.

Sorry, but can you explain why you think this identity should be easier to establish than the one in the linked question? My doubt is simply that proving a product of two sums is equal to another product of two sums seems harder than showing one sum is equal to another sum...

That's precisely the point!  There are very few known "multiplicative" methods for proving identities (basically, one generally has to express each of the factors in this identity as multiplicative combinations of common terms); nevertheless, we know indirectly that this identity is true (by a route which would have been extremely hard to motivate just from the form of this character identity).  This to me is an incongruous discrepancy that calls out for further explanation.

In particular, the answer to this question may reveal a new (or old, but very obscure) way to prove multiplicative identities.  Basically, this identity is signalling a mysterious breakdown of the unique factorization property (fundamental theorem of arithmetic) for character sums, and I would like to know why this is the case.

I'm curious as well as to what is behind this identity.

I'll try to evaluate all four sums in terms of $L$-values $A:=L(0,\chi)$ and $B:=L(0,\chi\chi_3)$, where $\chi_3$ is the non-principal character $\mod 3$. Let $N=2n-1$. First of all, if $\chi$ is a non-principal character with period $q$ (not necessarily $\mod q$) then we have a formula in terms of Hurwitz zeta-function:
$$
L(0,\chi)=\sum_{r=1}^{q}\chi(r)\zeta\left(0,\frac{r}{q}\right).
$$
Next, $\zeta(0,a)=\frac12-a$ and the sum of $\chi$ over full period is $0$, so
$$
L(0,\chi)=-\frac{1}{q}\sum_{r=1}^{q}r\chi(r).
$$
We are going to use this formula a lot. Next, let $\chi_{0,3}$ and $\chi_{0,6}$ be the principal characters $\mod 3$ and $6$. Then due to Euler product formula we have
$$
L(0,\chi\chi_{0,3})=A(1-\chi(3))\\
L(0,\chi\chi_{0,6})=A(1-\chi(3))(1-\chi(2))\\
L(0,\chi\chi_3\chi_{0,6})=B(1+\chi(2)).
$$
Now, let $f:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb C$ be a $3$-periodic function. Then
$$
f(n)=a_0(f)+a_1(f)\chi_{0,3}(n)+a_2(f)\chi_3(n),
$$
where $a_0(f)=f(0)$, $a_1(f)=\frac{f(1)+f(2)}{2}-f(0)$, $a_2(f)=\frac{f(1)-f(2)}{2}$. Consequently, for any such function we get
$$
\sum_{r=1}^{3N}rf(r)\chi(r)=-3N(a_0(f)L(0,\chi)+a_1(f)L(0,\chi\chi_{0,3})+a_2(f)L(0,\chi\chi_3))=-3N(A(a_0(f)+a_1(f)(1-\chi(3)))+Ba_2(f)).
$$
Let us use this to evaluate second and third sums (we denote the $i$-th sum by $S_i$). For the third sum:
$$
S_3=\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}j\chi(6j+2)=\chi(2)\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}j\chi(3j+1)=\chi(2)\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}(j+\frac13)\chi(3j+1)=\\
=\frac{\chi(2)}{3}\sum_{0\leq r<3N, r=3j+1}r\chi(r)=\frac{\chi(2)}{6}\sum_{0\leq r<3N}r(\chi_{0,3}(r)+\chi_3(r))\chi(r)=\frac{\chi(2)}{6}(-3N)(L(0,\chi\chi_{0,3})+L(0,\chi\chi_3))=-\frac{\chi(2)N}{2}(A(1-\chi(3))+B).
$$
For the second sum, consider
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{3N}k\omega^{Nk}\chi(k).
$$
By $N$-periodicity of $\chi$, we can split it into three and group them together
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{N}(k\omega^{Nk}+(k+N)\omega^{Nk+N^2}+(k+2N)\omega^{Nk+2N^2})\chi(k).
$$
Next, $N^2\equiv 1 \pmod 3$, so $\omega^{N^2}=\omega$ and we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{N}\omega^{Nk}\chi(k)(k+(k+N)\omega+(k+2N)\omega^2)=-N(\omega+2)\sum_{k=1}^{N}\omega^{Nk}\chi(k).
$$
This last sum is clearly $S_2$, hence
$$
S_2=-\frac{1}{N(\omega+2)}\sum_{k=1}^{3N}k\omega^{Nk}\chi(k).
$$
The sum on the right can be evaluated as above: for the function $k\mapsto \omega^{Nk}$ we get $a_0=1, a_1=-\frac32, a_2=\frac{\omega^{2N}-\omega^N}{2}$, hence the sum is
$$
-3N((-A/2-3A\chi(3)/2)+B/2(\omega^{2N}-\omega^N)).
$$
Therefore,
$$
S_2=-\frac{3}{2(\omega+2)}(A(1+3\chi(3))+B(\omega^{N}-\omega^{2N})).
$$
Next, the first sum is
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}j\chi(6j+1)=\frac16 \sum_{0<r\leq 6N, r=6j+1}r\chi(r)=\frac{1}{12}\sum_{0<r\leq 6N}r(\chi_{0,6}(r)+\chi_{0,6}\chi_3(r))\chi(r)=-\frac{N}{2}(L(0,\chi\chi_{0,6})+L(0,\chi\chi_3\chi_{0,6}))=-\frac{N}{2}(A(1-\chi(3))(1-\chi(2))+B(1+\chi(2)))
$$
As for the fourth sum, consider
$$
\sum_{|k|<3N/2}k\chi(k)\omega^{2Nk}.
$$
Shifting the variable by $\pm N$, we obtain, similarly to the previous
$$
\sum_{|k|<3N/2}k\chi(k)\omega^{2Nk}=-N(2\omega+1)\sum_{|k|\leq N/2}\chi(k)\omega^{2Nk}.
$$
Next, let $\psi$ be a non-principal character with odd period $q$. How do we evaluate
$$
\sum_{|k|<q/2}k\psi(k)?
$$
If $\psi$ is even, we get $0$. If $\psi$ is odd, we get
$$
2\sum_{0<k<q/2}k\psi(k)=\frac{1}{\psi(2)}\sum_{k<q, k \text{ even}}k\psi(k).
$$
Changing $k$ to $q-k$ makes $k$ odd and $\psi(q-k)=-\psi(k)$, so
$$
\sum_{k<q, k \text{ even}}k\psi(k)=\sum_{k<q, k\text{ odd}}(q-k)(-\psi(k)).
$$
This means that
$$
2\sum_{k<q, k\text{ even}}k\psi(k)=-qL(0,\psi)+q\sum_{k<q, k\text{ even}}\psi(k).
$$
Next,
$$
-2q(1-\psi(2))L(0,\psi)=-2qL(0,\psi\psi_{0,2})=\sum_{k<2q}k\psi(k)\chi_{0,2}(k)=\\
=\sum_{k<q, \text{odd}}k\psi(k)+\sum_{k<q, \text{even}}(k+q)\psi(k).
$$
Therefore we get for odd $\psi$
$$
\sum_{|k|<q/2}k\psi(k)=-\frac{2qL(0,\psi)(1-\psi(2))}{\psi(2)}.
$$
After that we should expand $\omega^{2Nk}$ into sum of characters $\mod 3$. We are going to get two cases depending on whether $\chi(-1)=1$ or $-1$. After that, one should collect all this stuff together and compare the coefficients. One more simple observation is that due to the functional equation $L(0,\chi)=0$ for even characters, hence etiher $A$ or $B$ is always $0$.
P.S. If needed, I can complete the computation 100% somewhat later.

After all, this identity is more like $AB=CD$ for $A=xy, B=zt, C=xz, D=yt$ for appropriately chosen $x,y,z,t$ than a breakedown of unique factorization.

Do you think your proof reveals other possible scenarios? Say, instead of the above setup with $\gcd(2n-1,3)=1$, perhaps $\gcd(2n-1,p)$ for other primes; or, things like $\gcd(3n-1,2)=1$, etc.? Or, is what we have here a "singular" instance?

If you complete the calculation (possibly splitting into odd and even cases earlier in the argument to clean up the formulas, at the cost of doubling the length), I will be happy to accept this as an answer.  The upshot seems to be that in the odd case all four sums are multiples of $L(0,\chi) = -\frac{1}{N} \sum_{r=1}^N r \chi(r)$ by elementary factors, and in the even case all four sums are multiples of $L(0,\chi\chi_3) = -\frac{1}{3N} \sum_{r=1}^{3N} r \chi(r) \chi_3(r)$ by elementary factors, which largely explains the multiplicative identity after computing the elementary factors.
